# iScroll Ajax content

Tags: ajax, iscroll

i have problem with refreshing content in wrapper after it is loaded by ajax.

When i check with firebug - XHR is showing request and i can see elements loaded but it isn't showing on page.

This is what i am using for pullDown function to get ajax content

```
function pullDownAction () {
    setTimeout(function () {   
        var el, li, i;
        el = document.getElementById('thelist');
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = window.location;
        http.open("GET",url,true);
        http.send();
        myScroll.destroy();
                myScroll = null;
                loaded();
  }, 1000);   
}
```

It looks like as content is stuck between showing on webpage and ajax request.

Any idea?

Comment: Please post some code how you are appending the dynamic content to the html tags. Instead if using myScroll.destroy() use myScroll.refresh().

Answer (score 0):

`myScroll.refresh()` (instead of .destroy() and recalling "loaded()") should do the trick!
If you're using IScroll4 you can try to use the `checkDOMChanges:true` option of iscroll.

If it still won't work - it could be a CSS issue caused by the scroll-wrapper (#scroller) not expanding with its content. (`float`,`position:absolute;` or something like that)

EDIT: it seems to me as you're not handling a responseText of the request at all!

According to [this example](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#Codebeispiele_.28JavaScript.29) you need an event handler for the `onreadystatechange` event:

```
 http.open("GET",url,true);
 http.onreadystatechange = function () {
       if (http.readyState == 4) {
          alert(http.responseText); //handle this response! (i.e. writing to an element's innerHTML)
      }
 };
 http.send(null);
```